# Buffer allocation in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, allocation

I want to use a buffer to store a sparse index. 
If I allocate a buffer of, say, 1024 bytes, and store effectively 128 bytes in it, how many bytes will be allocated in memory?

Comment: What are you calling a buffer ? a string ? a byte array ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: that may be not a part of v8 but of node js

Answer (score 1):

According to the constructor doc:

**new Buffer(size)#**

`size` Number
Allocates a new buffer of size bytes. size must be less than `1,073,741,824` bytes (1 GB) on 32 bits architectures or `2,147,483,648` bytes (2 GB) on 64 bits architectures, otherwise a `RangeError` is thrown.

Unlike ArrayBuffers, **the underlying memory for buffers is not initialized**. So the contents of a newly created Buffer are unknown and could contain sensitive data. Use `buf.fill(0)` to initialize a buffer to zeroes.

It seem that the whole memory is allocated, but not zeroified.

Comment: Yes, I have read that, but I was thinking of a possible memory allocation optimisation. If not I will do my own.